# Restheart get collection count()

Tags: mongodb, restheart

How can i call this mongo-shell command:

```
db.coll.count()
```

using restheart?

I tried this:

```
http GET 127.0.0.1:8080/cloneGame/players/_count
```

but got 403 Forbidden Error. Is there something wrong with my authentification?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You get the count of the collection adding the *count* query parameter to the request URL.

With it RESTHeart adds the *_size* property to the response.

If you are only interested on getting the count of the collection (without GETting  documents) you can do:

```
http GET 127.0.0.1:8080/cloneGame/players?count\&pagesize=0
```

More info in the [Query Documents](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/XACk) documentation section.

Comment: Andrea we need to double check this, in my case I'm getting all the documents even if I add the &pagesize=0. It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Maurizio, you probably need to escape the & otherwise the terminal will interpret it as the background operator, I have updated the answer accordingly